# Google Site in google Apps external site?

Tags: dns, sites

I have a Google Apps account with domain bought, through Google. 
I can create sites, but they will only be available to users within this domain.

Question: How to create an external site - Like a company site?

One solution is to use App Engine, but it seems strange that it is not possible within google Apps. Using Sites and all the templates look lige real external sites, therefore it must be possible - Am I missing something.

Thanks in advence
Christian

Comment: What makes you think Google Sites created in an Apps domain are only available to people within the domain?

Comment: Well they are available, but mapping a site to a domain will just redirect to sites.google.com/a/domainname.com. Also, you will have to login. Thanks

Comment: I found the problem - it turned out that in Google Apps Dashboard you set if users should be able to make sites public.. and it even goes for admins :-)

I am now able to share the site, and make it public - before it was only posible to to give access to the site internely to the domain.

Wupi, it all works

Happy Apps Regards Christian

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem - it turned out that in Google Apps Dashboard you set if users should be able to make sites public.. and it even goes for admins :-)

I am now able to share the site, and make it public - before it was only posible to to give access to the site internely to the domain.

Wupi, it all works
Regards
Christian